# analogWrite(DAC0, X), Analog voltage on DAC0 pin is higher for lower X value - is this normal?

Tags: arduino-due, analogwrite, digital-analog-conversion

I am using an [Arduino DUE](http://www.robgray.com/temp/Due-pinout-WEB.png). Using the `analogWrite(DAC0, X)` command I am writing an analog value to this pin. X = 0 - 255 as I understand it.

I am observing that when X is lower, the voltage on DAC0 is higher nad when X is higher the voltage is lower.

Is that expected?

My code is simple:

```cpp
void setup() 
{
  analogWriteResolution(12);
}

void loop() 
{
  analogWrite(DAC0, 10 );  
}
```

Comment: `voltage is lower` ... how do you know what the output voltage is? ... you have not described how you are measuring the voltage.

Comment: Using a DMM between the DAC0 pin and GND.

Comment: I don't understand. How else does one measure voltage?

Comment: @jsotola  The load? I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: Look, comments under questions are for clarifying the question, not trying to answer them obliquely or not. If you want to ask under what load the measurement was made, then ask it.

Answer (score -1):

That doesn’t sound right. Try setting **x** to 0 and measure with DC. You should get ~0.56 V. Repeat with 4095, and you should get ~2.76 V.

Also, note that with `analogWriteResolution(12)` your range is not 8-bits (0-255), but 12-bits (0-4095).

The output should follow:

**V<sub>out</sub> = V<sub>ref</sub> <sub>*</sub> <sup>X<sub>in</sub></sup>⧸<sub>(2<sup>N</sup>-1)</sub> + V<sub>offset</sub>**

where

- V<sub>offset</sub> = 0.56 V
- V<sub>ref</sub> = 2.2 V
- 0 ≤ X<sub>in</sub> ≤ 4095

Comment: According to [the page about analogWrite](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/): *Unlike the PWM pins, DAC0 and DAC1 are Digital to Analog converters, and act as true analog outputs.* - so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @NickGammon Oops, that slipped passed me. I'll edit. Thanks